# Why is the US continuing to send the last military aid to Ukraine when it won't be enough to make a difference?

Tags: united-states, ukraine, foreign-aid

According to the [Euro News](https://www.euronews.com/2023/12/28/us-sends-last-military-aid-to-ukraine-for-now):

> The United States announced on Wednesday it had released its last tranche of military aid for Ukraine. The White House approved $250 million (€225 million) in support, but more will need fresh approval from Congress. Negotiations between Republicans and Democrats have stalled.

If Ukraine could not achieve anything with [$75 billion](https://www.cfr.org/article/how-much-aid-has-us-sent-ukraine-here-are-six-charts), how could it with $0.25 billion? So why is the US bothering to send more military aid to Ukraine when it won't be enough to make a difference?

**Edit: (29/12/2023)** I wasn't aware about the current situation in Ukraine because of Gaza heartbreaking situation but now I remembered what made me to think that my question is valid. I noticed that **The Washington Post has removed the [tab dedicated to the war in Ukraine](https://twitter.com/nexta_tv/status/1737515279645659321) from its front page**, so I thought this might be the final aid.

Comment: "to make a difference" That part is s but unclear to me. Could it be clarified? I'm sure that even with military equipment worth 250 million USD, one can achieve something if only last longer for example. What kind of magnitude for a difference that counts were you thinking of?

Comment: Voting not to close - It's a reasonable doubt to have if one is ignorant about the cost of war and the politics behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anybody familiar with Biden wouldn't be surprised by this tactic. He is an old school "cold war" U.S. politician who once publicly pointed out how the $3 billion given to [Israel was the "best investment"](https://youtube.com/shorts/2HZs-v0PR44) the US ever made in the middle-east - i.e. **they essentially got an ally willing to military commit themselves for US strategic goals in a region**. A *Fortune* report - [Biden pitches tens of billions of dollars in aid for Ukraine and Israel in rare Oval Office address: ‘A smart investment that’s going to pay dividends’](https://web.archive.org/web/20231027145612/https://fortune.com/2023/10/20/biden-oval-office-address-aid-ukraine-israel-us-security/) - highlights that Biden thinks similarly about Ukraine and, apparently Taiwan too:

> Declaring that U.S. leadership “holds the world together,” President Joe Biden told Americans on Thursday night the country must deepen its support of Ukraine and Israel in the middle of two vastly different, unpredictable and bloody wars. ... He’s expected to ask for $105 billion on Friday, including $60 billion for Ukraine, much of which would replenish U.S. weapons stockpiles provided earlier. There’s also $14 billion for Israel, $10 billion for unspecified humanitarian efforts, $14 billion for managing the U.S.-Mexico border and fighting fentanyl trafficking and $7 billion for the Indo-Pacific region, which includes Taiwan. The proposal was described by three people familiar with the details who insisted on anonymity before the official announcement.
>
> ***“It’s a smart investment that’s going to pay dividends for American security for generations,”*** Biden said. *(Emphais added)*

That's why, in real politic terms, the US aid shouldn't just be considered based on the advantage it brings to Ukraine but also on how it strategically benefits the US. As a Center for Strategic and International Studies report titled "[United States Aid to Ukraine: An Investment Whose Benefits Greatly Exceed its Cost](https://www.csis.org/analysis/united-states-aid-ukraine-investment-whose-benefits-greatly-exceed-its-cost)" points out:

> **Focusing on the price tag of aid instead of the value of what it buys ignores the fact that the war in Ukraine has become the equivalent of a proxy war with Russia, and a war that can be fought without any U.S. military casualties**, that unites most of the world’s democracies behind a common cause, that deeply punishes Russia for its act of aggression and strengthens every aspect of deterrence. It ignores the fact that **costs of such aid are low in grand strategic terms**, and seem likely to be far lower than the cumulative cost of the fighting to save an Afghan government that never began to approach the Ukraine’s unity and national commitment to defend itself.
>
> It not only ignores the moral and ethical commitment the U.S. should have to every other free nation, but it also ignores the fact that **Russia is far poorer than the U.S. and its allies**. It ignores the fact that **Russia is already paying far more of its Gross National Product and economy to fight the war in the Ukraine than the U.S. and its partners**, and that **Russia has suffered massive losses of weapons, war reserves, and military personnel**.
>
> As is discussed in detail later in this analysis, **U.S. aid has so far enabled Ukraine to do immense damage to Russia’s overall capability** to threaten Europe and to fight any future conflict.
>
> It ignores the practical benefits of the message that sending such aid to the Ukraine has sent to our strategic partners and allies about American capability and resolve. It ignores the extent to which such aid has put practical limits on Putin’s ambitions to restore a greater Russia, and **shown other states that they can trust the U.S. to compete with China**. It ignores the extent to which **such aid helps to rebuild and strengthen the role America** plays as the de facto leader of the West and other democratic states. It ignores the degree to which **it has revitalized NATO and European defense effort**.
>
> ... while U.S. aid to Ukraine has scarcely been cheap, **U.S. spending has been at token levels compared to the economic burden that the cost of the Ukraine war and economic sanctions have placed on Russia**. Once aid spending is put in the context of American economic strength and leverage, **it allows the U.S. to exert immense strategic leverage on Russia at a minimal cost to the U.S.** and in ways that U.S. spending on military forces – vital as it is to U.S. security -- cannot match.
>
> ... **Providing aid to Ukraine effectively has forced Russia to fight a proxy war in which both the U.S. and Europe could exploit the fact they have a massive strategic advantage in both defense spending and total economic resources.**
>
> ... The U.S. investment in aid to Ukraine, and Ukrainian military success has had many other grand strategic benefits. The **Ukraine’s military successes have exposed Russia’s many military weaknesses**, gave the U.S. and NATO a priceless insight into Russia’s limits and vulnerabilities, **led Sweden and Finland to apply to join NATO**, and led many NATO states – including key cases Germany – to announce plans to revitalize their forces in ways where a decade of NATO efforts to persuade them to spend 2% of their GDP on defense failed to accomplish.
>
> ... **Nothing else the U.S. could have done – or spent defense and aid funds upon – could have been as productive in ensuring the security of the United States against one of the two major powers that could threaten the U.S.** as well as its partners and allies. Nothing the U.S. can do in the future will be as productive in showing allies and partners that collective efforts to defend can secure Europe and the Atlantic, and help rebuild strategic confidence and trust in the U.S. *(All emphasis added)*.

Even though U.S. General Mark A. Milley, the Chairman of the U.S. Joint Chief of Staff, has publicly said that he doesn't believe Ukraine can defeat Russia militarily and should negotiate for a "pragmatic peace settlement", the Russians are unwilling to offer reasonable terms to Zelensky because of his own amateur political moves. (He once pretended to negotiate in good faith with them, while he had no real intention to settle, and so he has lost lost all credibility with the Russians and they aren't willing to grant any concessions to him. He further made the political mistake of passing a law that Ukraine won't negotiate with Putin / Russia and so now can't negotiate for peace with Russia without losing political face in Ukraine.) So Zelensky now feels trapped in a political web of his own making, and feels he has no options but to keep fighting.

The US is willing to oblige him because completely abandoning it will invite criticism of using Ukranians. And ofcourse, it continues to benefit whether Ukraine wins or loses. (Note also that a substantially weakened Ukrainian Army is also beneficial to NATO because if Ukraine cannot join NATO, it could revert to ally with Russia again in the future.)

Answer (score 8):

> **Question:**
>
> Why is the US sending the last military aid to Ukraine when we all know that this aid will not change the war Result?

Foreign Military Aid to Ukraine has already changed the war result.  Ukraine has reclaimed 54 percent of the land Russia has captured since the beginning of the war, according to a New York Times analysis of data provided by the Institute for the Study of War.

Originally many in the West thought Russia would roll over Ukraine in a matter of days, and the West was preparing for a government in exile and a long asymmetric war.  Due to the heart of the Ukrainian people and Western aid, they've rolled back Russian aggression and are standing toe to toe with the Russians slugging this thing out. **[Russia only controls 18% of Ukraine today.](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/world/europe/ukraine-maps.html)**.  I'd say that's an accomplishment given Russia is 28 times Ukraine's size and 4 times their population.

So if you think this "last" tranche of U.S. aid is it; I think you've been reading too much Russian propaganda.  There are a handful of Congressmen and Senators holding up aid.  That is a temporary obstacle.  The E.U. and the rest of the pro-Ukrainian coalition will pick up some of the slack while the U.S. gets its Putin/Orbán/ Lukashenko apologists in order.

> Update: My simple argument for why this aid will not change the war Result: If Ukraine could not achieve anything with $75 billion, how could it be with $0.25 billion?

Could Not achieve anything?  They've retaken more than half of the land Russia took initially and they currently hold 82% of their country and in 2 years they've killed more than 3x's the number of Russians who died in the Afghan War in 10 years (conservatively).

The first squadron of F-16s went operational in Ukraine 4 days ago with pretty dramatic effects.  Just ask the Russian space command or navy.  The weapons the West is providing Ukraine are just going to get more and more advanced in 2024, and $0.25 Billion is just the last U.S. aid for 2023.

Most of the American voters know what happens historically if you let an aggressor enjoy a victory in Europe.  That will cost the U.S. a lot more than if we doubled or tripled U.S. aid to Ukraine in 2024.

Comment: You mean the US __may__ send new aids in 2024?

Comment: Stats here: https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2023/12/08/about-half-of-republicans-now-say-the-us-is-providing-too-much-aid-to-ukraine/  It still does not look as decided.

Comment: _I think you've been reading too much Russian propaganda_ No. I usually read NYT, The Guardian and some others. But for the past 3 months I have never read anything but the Gaza war.

Comment: Reference for the last paragraph?

Comment: “Tranche”, not “trench” of aid

Comment: @C.F.G  No I don't mean **may**,  You've got a pro Ukraine aid President and that's really all it took to get military aid to Britain during the Battle of Britain in WWII.  But on top of that you've got the majority of the Senate and House behind Ukraine aid.  Literally what's holding it up is a handful of Congressmen and a handful of Senators.   That is by no means insurmountable.

Comment: @Stančikas  FYI,  The republicans have underperformed in every election since 2020.  They are about to nominate a candidate for president who is a convicted sex offender, a court recognized insurrectionist with around 100 felony charges pending.  His follower's debate whether he could serve as president from jail.   He also had his campaign manager and national security advisor jailed for working for Russian intelligence.  Those are not the guys who will be determining US foreign policy.   Those are the guys who throw monkey wrenches into the works as the country winces.

Comment: An aside: there's no indication that Russia's recent Su-34 losses were due to F-16s; the leading theory [appears to be](https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/ukraine-says-it-shot-down-three-russian-su-34-fullbacks) Patriot missiles. But as Patriots are *also* Western-donated gear, it's not much difference.

Comment: @JMS So why the Washington Post has removed the [tab dedicated to the war in Ukraine from its front page](https://twitter.com/nexta_tv/status/1737515279645659321).

Comment: @Cadence, The F-16 is an eye in the sky which extends visibility. It selects what target to destroy, fully integrated with the Patriot, the Storm Shadow Cruise missiles, and JDAM munitions previously provided. Doesn't matter if the munitions are under the wing of the aircraft. The F-16 makes all the western munitions way more effective. Previously munitions where just fired off in the general direction of the threats and the munition chose the target. Now with the F-16's they have complete visibility of those threats and can select which to engage with which munition at a greater distance.

Comment: I don't like this question, but I like even less this answer. Weapons don't win wars unless you have truly a massive tech gap like Spain had against Aztecs, or USA in Afhganistan (and yet...). Russia is not losing this war because their weapons are crap. Ukraine halted, and then counter-punched the initial assault with even older soviet equipment. It's now, with newer NATO gear, when they're failing to make advances. Russia made every mistake they could at the start of the war. Now they're not making as many, and western weapons fail to live up to the hype predicted, whether Leopards of F16.

Comment: @Rekesoft,  In Dec 2023 **[U.S. intelligence claimed Russia has lost 315,000 troops from the estimated 360,000 who took part in the invasion,](https://www.newsweek.com/russia-ukraine-losses-staggering-year-1856852)**   Weapons do win wars, and the lack of weapons is a sure fire formula for losing wars.  The 4, 5 decades old western weapons provided to Ukraine are technologically superior to what Russia is fielding,  Russia just has more,  and are more willing to sacrifice their young men.  The only chance Russia has in this war is if the West gives up.

Comment: @JMS Claiming is easy. I can claim many things too. Lack of weapons certainly can lose wars, but I don't see Russia is lacking them. For sure, if NATO stops supplying them to Ukraine they are going to lose this war, but that doesn't mean that if they keep providing them they are going to win. Ukraine didn't need an "eye in the sky" earlier in the conflict, when Russia was using centralized ammo depots and sending waves of tanks through the same spots. Now that they have it, Russia is not providing easy targets anymore.

Comment: @Rekesoft Russia is providing easy targets.   What once was safe isn't any-longer.    **[Ukraine downs 5 planes in 3 days](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/25/world/europe/ukraine-downs-planes-russia-claims-town.html)**,   **[Ukraine blows up $250 million Yastreb-AV](https://www.technology.org/2024/01/03/ukrainian-himars-destroyed-an-extremely-expensive-russian-radar/)**,  **[Ukraine Destroys Three Russian Tank Battalions in a Single Week](https://www.newsweek.com/ukraine-russia-tank-losses-armored-vehicles-donetsk-avdiivka-1847049)**   and then their is the the Novocherkassk  landing ship

Answer (score 5):

There are currently no any obvious events in the front that would show imminent victory of Russia comming fast. Russia still needs to take somewhat 80% of the territory, and no single major city has been taken in all 2023. War often prefers the defender. Lots of military help like fighter jets are still being delivered.

[For instance](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidaxe/2023/12/30/killing-russians-by-the-truckload-around-avdiivka-ukraines-m-2-fighting-vehicles-are-showing-how-russia-loses-and-ukraine-wins/?sh=6a5c12151ed6), the 47th Brigade got all 190 M-2s that the United States pledged to the Ukrainian war effort early this year. The brigade has lost about 30 so far, and with high cost to the enemy. These 75 billion you talk about are still "working".

If the 300 bn of Russian assets will be seized at the end, this is more than all help so far provided.

Russia started from saying only professional soldiers will go to the front. Now mostly any able man can be drafted at any time. Biden surely knows the history of his own country: once USA started [such a draft](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_lottery_(1969)) during Vietnam War, this soon made the war highly unpopular.

In such a context, any help matters and the winner is not clear. Biden is doing what he still can and lets others to know.

Comment: I'd add that if the U.S. gives aid to Ukraine and then Ukraine's government falls to Russia's invasion, the aid could help the defenders in a resistance-level consideration.

Comment: *Russia still needs to take 80% of the territory* - No, it doesn't. Putin made a statement in and around **2008** declaring that, *"If Ukraine joins NATO, it will do so without Crimea and the eastern regions"* (source: [All the Kremlin's Men: Inside the Court of Vladimir Putin](https://www.libraryjournal.com/review/all-the-kremlins-men-inside-the-court-of-vladimir-putin) by Mikhail Zygar). And that's exactly where Russian military are, so far. Odessa may also be a future target if Ukraine chooses to fight on, as that will make Ukraine a landlocked country completely dependent on the west.

Comment: What do you mean by _80% of the territory_ ? 80% of Ukraine or 80% of Western Ukraine?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of aid also has more abstract goals beyond changing the outcome of the present war (and that outcome itself is not a simple binary distinction between "Ukraine wins" and "Russia wins"; there are a huge range of possibilities you might want to affect even if it can't change who "wins").

One thing international aid to Ukraine has *definitely* achieved is making this whole conquest **MUCH** more expensive for Russia than its government originally assumed it would be. That's still true even if Russia does ultimately achieve goals it is happy with. That cost will factor in to the decision making process the *next* time Russia (or perhaps even some other power) is considering a similar war of aggression. If Russia had known in advance how the war would go up till now, would they have started it? We can't *know*, but my guess is no.

So the biggest benefit may be in the form of future wars that now will never happen. That effect is completely invisible and nearly impossible to measure, so no one will ever say "Ah, here's where those billions of dollars in aid to Ukraine paid off for us". But if you could somehow compare diverging timelines in order to attribute this sort of deterrent effect to the dollars that have been spent, I suspect you would find they have saved a huge number of lives (and dollars) that would otherwise have been lost in future wars. Even if Russia ultimately triumphs over Ukraine, that would be a benefit it still makes sense to try to increase by sending the aid the US is presently authorised to send.